# ios AUAudioUnit registerSubclass and select in AVAudioUnit instantiate

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I have registered two classes with

```
AUAudioUnit.registerSubclass(
            myAudioUnit1.self,
            as: componentDescription1,
            name: "myAudioUnit1",
            version: 1)
```

and

```
AUAudioUnit.registerSubclass(
            myAudioUnit2.self,
            as: componentDescription2,
            name: "myAudioUnit2",
            version: 1)
```

Then I instantiate two AVAudioUnits with

```
AVAudioUnit.instantiate(
  with: componentDescription1, options: .init(rawValue: 0)) { 
    (avAudioUnit, error) in 
        self.audioEngine!.attach(avAudioUnit!)
        self.audioEngine!.connect(avAudioUnit!,
        to: self.audioEngine!.mainMixerNode, format: outFormat)
}
```

and

```
AVAudioUnit.instantiate(
  with: componentDescription2, options: .init(rawValue: 0)) { 
    (avAudioUnit, error) in 
        self.audioEngine!.attach(avAudioUnit!)
        self.audioEngine!.connect(avAudioUnit!,
        to: self.audioEngine!.mainMixerNode, format: outFormat)
}
```

The first object should be based on the first registered class definition, the second object based on the second registered definition. Unfortunately, instantiate only uses the class definition registered first. How can I select which class definition to use?

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you're using the code right.  Maybe there's a typo somewhere. Is myAudioUnit1 a class or an instance?  Could you show the component descriptions as well?